# OpenAM policy creation issue: could not add/authenticate Groups other than of master realm

Tags: openam, opendj

While creating OpenAM policy i couldn't find Group from same user store (can see groups in master realm).

Realm: / (Top Level Realm)  >  **testRealm**

Group in masterRealm: **masterGroup**

Group in testRealm: **testGroup**

Users in testGroup: admin

Create Policy(in testRealm) -> Define Subject Conditions ->

Type: Users&Groups
Group Subjects: doesn't shows "testGroup" in auto completion text box (but shows masterGroup).
Also i can see user "admin" in "User Subjects"

### Why i am not able to see "testGroup"?

I created policy using "/policies" API with group name "testGroup".
Users in testGroup: admin

when executes policy evaluation API it returns empty attributes.

when i tried with user name "admin" in "User Subjects" box, policy evaluation API gives values.

Whats the issue with Groups in sub Realm in Policy?

Comment: Its a bug. Issue resolved in OpenAM 13.0.0.

Answer (score 0):

issue already reported in JIRA.

https://bugster.forgerock.org/jira/browse/OPENAM-5386